# xCode Archive gets automatically cancelled just before finishing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to archive somebody else's project which I made some modifications. Archiving takes more than 15 minutes and, only 2 out-of 25 times succeeded. xCode Archive gets automatically cancelled just before finishing. I tried many different approaches but no luck. Can somebody help me ?

[image]

- MacOs Catalina 10.15.6
- xCode 11.6
- no Run scripts
- Uses following cocopods

  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.2'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView'
  pod 'SDWebImage'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'